# Through code I can not generate text in iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

here the code of my iFrame but text is not actually shown in the frame

```
.iframe {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: lighter;
    background-attachment: inherit;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: top;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal;
    float: inherit right;
    widows:inherit;
    volume:silent;
    border-left-style: dashed;
    list-style-type: circle;
    cursor: default;
    filter: Glow(Color=#345, Strength=2);
}
```

code for frame in html tag

```
  <iframe class="iframe" align="middle" height="500" width="1000">
      <font color="#00FF33" style="animation:ease-in-out" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-    serif">hello guys i am dhaiwat....</font>
  </iframe>
```

how can get the text inside it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<iframe>` content is set by the url attribute like this: `url="http://example.com"`. The actual page (in this case examplel.com) is loaded in the iframe box. For setting regular content you should use `<div>`,`<span>` or other semantics.

A good reference is w3schools ([link1](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp), [link2](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/)) where you can find a lot of information about html tags.

PS: the `<font>` tag is deprecated, so you shouldnt use it anymore

Answer (score 0):

Your missing an  tag. also are you trying to get the page inside the frame itself to be specific. The page being loaded in the frame will have to be specified using its own dependencies